# Are pg-promise tasks atomic?

Tags: pg-promise

Pretty simple question but I can't find the answer anywhere.

The `pg-promise` docs say that we should avoid using transactions because they're blocking operations and that we should be using tasks instead. https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#tx

But what happens when a query inside of a task fails? Will the whole task be rolled back?

In other words, are tasks atomic?

Comment: Was my answer somehow not satisfactory? You still haven't responded.

Comment: Thanks for your help @vitaly-t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tasks (method [task](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#task)) are there simply to let you execute multiple queries against the same allocated connection from the pool. They are not atomic.

A transaction (method [tx](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#tx)) extends the task with automatic injection of `BEGIN` +  `COMMIT`/`ROLLBACK`. Every transaction is atomic.

Also, each [multi](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#multi)-query is atomic, as documented, which is enforced by PostgreSQL.

> The `pg-promise` docs say that we should avoid using transactions because they're blocking operations and that we should be using tasks instead.

That advise is given in the context of executing multiple queries where none of the query changes the database, like `SELECT`-s. If you are changing data, that advise does not apply.

From the [tx](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#tx) documentation:

> `Note that transactions should be chosen over tasks only where necessary, because unlike regular tasks, transactions are blocking operations`.